# How to professionally deal with a bad boss?

Tags: management, work-environment, mental-health

I am weary, kinda frustrated. I am unhappy. I am demotivated. My interaction with my boss leaves me cold. Sometimes he's kinda bully, intrusive, controlling, picky or petty. I am wondering how can I professionally deal with this boss.

My boss takes credit for my work, never provides positive feedback and misses each meeting that was scheduled with you nor with clients. He's never recognizes my "excellent performance" nor that of any other employee, so the office is joyless and unhappy.

What should I do with this kind of environment?

Comment: How big is your company?

Comment: Around 100 people, but in my division we only have less than 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there was no other answer yet but "leave!":

Option A:
Be friendly, supportive, but not afraid to even oppose him in a friendly way. Do show him problems you see, but do not try to "win" any discussion. Also make sure he never looses face. Try to find out where he will appreciate kind words and support.
In a way: Be the calm and friendly "adult" of the two of you.
You will not be able to make a great boss out of a bad one, but you might find a better way to live with each other.

Option B:
Ask your boss's boss if you can be placed in some other place of the company's hierarchy. You do not need to stress (or even mention) the short-commings of your current boss. Simply use "I-messages" and say something like "I feel uncomfortable working with X. I think he is a very capable person, but I am not very compatible. I could be more productive for the company working for a different superior."

Option C:
Try to get *him* out of the company. This is a whole new topic/question in it's own (or even several), so I will not elaborate here. But it *is* an option that might be viable in some circumstances.

Comment: Option A is the best way, so long as your attitude is about getting paid, not having your hand held it's works out.

Answer (score 7):

> What should I do with this kind of environment?

Not to sound negative but this kind of environment seems unhealthy and a place where you wouldn't want to be.

Being honest, you can't actually make your boss change or be more happy/motivating.

Adding to that the fact that he is taking credit of your work tells me that you should consider updating your resume and start job hunting ASAP.